# Regex: conditional matching of substrings within parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have a corpus of texts from live TV segments, and I am trying to find a way to remove references to prerecorded segments or commercial breaks with regex. Consider the following example script symptomatic of the type of text I'm working with:

```
myconvo = "speaker1: hello

          speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said last week

          (begin audio clip)

          Ted Cruz (R-TX): My dad did not shoot JFK, why do people keep saying that?

          (end audio clip)

          speaker1: now isn't that interesting"
```

The corpus has been produced from different sources, with different standards (i.e. some use brackets, others use parentheses is one example). However, the above is a broad representation. To address the problem I have written the following:

```
cleanString = re.sub(r"\n[\(\[].+[\)\]]\n*[\.a-zA-Z\s\d,'’:;!?@£$\"“”-]*\n*[\(\[].+[\)\]]", '', myconvo)
```

For clarity, this script is written to do the following:

**1.** Look for a newline followed by open/closed brackets/parentheses with text in between (where the text denotes the beginning of the segment `\n[\(\[.+][\)\]]`

**2.** Look for any number of newlines followed by text that corresponds with the to-be deleted segment `\n*[\.a-zA-Z\s\d,'’:;!?@£$\"“”-]*`

**3.** Look for a newline followed by brackets/parenthesis containing the end of the to-be deleted segment

**4.** Replace with a blank space

This works in so far as the text to be deleted does not contain parentheses. However, it completely messes with the output if it does (which this and a number of others I have will).

I am wondering if there is a way I can specify the text to only apply at the beginning of a line, but I'm unsure how to go about this. I'll also point out that this is my first regex of anywhere near this length, so if someone has a better workaround I'd very much welcome input.

**EDIT:** For clarity, what I would hope to end up with is:

```
myconvo = "speaker1: hello

      speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said last week

      speaker1: now isn't that interesting"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import re

myconvo = """speaker1: hello

          speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said last week

          (begin audio clip)

          Ted Cruz (R-TX): My dad did not shoot JFK, why do people keep saying that?

          (end audio clip)

          speaker1: now isn't that interesting"""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):    
    myconvo = myconvo[0:match.start()] + myconvo[match.end():]
print(myconvo)
```

Gives output

```
speaker1: hello

          speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said    (begin audio clip)

          Ted Cruz (R-TX): My dad did not shoot JFK, why do people kee          (end audio clip)

          speaker1: now isn't that interesting
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `myconvo` string is not a valid Python string. But guessing looking at your regex that `(begin audio clip)` and `(end audio clip)` begin after newline characters and are terminated by newline characters, you might try:

```
r'\n\([^()]+\)\n.*?\n\([^()]+\)\n' with flags re.DOTALL
```

1. `\n` Matches a newline.
2. `\(` Matches `(`.
3. `[^()]`+ Matches 1 or more characters that are not `(` nor `)`.
4. `)` Matches `)`.
5. `\n` Matches a newline.
6. '.*?` A minimal match that will match anything up until the following.
7. `\n` Matches a newline.
8. `\(` Matches `(`.
9. `[^()]`+ Matches 1 or more characters that are not `(` nor `)`.
10. `)` Matches `)`.
11. `\n` Matches a newline.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bLrCI1/1/)

The code:

```
import re

myconvo = """speaker1: hello

speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said last week

(begin audio clip)

Ted Cruz (R-TX): My dad did not shoot JFK, why do people keep saying that?

(end audio clip)

speaker1: now isn't that interesting"""

myconvo = re.sub(r'\n\([^()]+\)\n.*?\n\([^()]+\)\n', '', myconvo, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(myconvo)
```

Prints:

```
speaker1: hello

speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said last week

speaker1: now isn't that interesting
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to take the optiona leading spaces from the example into account, you could match those as well.

To avoid the problem having the text also contain a bracket or parenthesis you could match all the lines in between that do not start with one using a negative lookahead `(?![^\S\r\n]*[\[\]()])`.

To match 0+ spaces you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\S\r\n]*` matching non a non whitespace char except a newline.

**Note** that matching `[` and `(` in the same character class and `]` and `)` as well, might also match `[` for opening and `)` for closing.

```
\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*[([].+[)\]](?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*[\[\]()]).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*[\{(].+\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFSGzx/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/o1RHFN)

Your code might look like

```
import re 
myconvo = """speaker1: hello

          speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said last week

          (begin audio clip)

          Ted Cruz (R-TX): My dad did not shoot JFK, why do people keep saying that?

          (end audio clip)

          speaker1: now isn't that interesting"""


regex = r"\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*[([].+[)\]](?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*[\[\]()]).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*[\{(].+\n"
result = re.sub(regex, "", myconvo)
print (result)
```

Output

```
speaker1: hello

          speaker2: hello (clears throat), let me show you something Ted Cruz said last week

          speaker1: now isn't that interesting
```

---

If all the lines do not have spaces at the start, you might could be:

```
\r?\n[([].+[)\]](?:\r?\n(?![\[\]()]).*)*\r?\n[\{(].+\r?\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cFRO7s/1/)